# use of unconstructed message in an orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-2013r2

I have this problem that I hope someone can help solve.

I have an orchestration that as input receive a file (message as Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Any). Just a file with some unstructured text.

I have created a Dynamic send port that save the received file in a backup folder.

The issue is that when someone send the same file (with the same filename), it doesn't overwrite the file in the backup folder.

when a try this following in a constructMessage shape

```
Message_new = orgMessage;
Message_new(FILE.CopyMode)= 2; //2=overwrite,
```

Both message are of same type: Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Any

I'm getting this error:

> Error 1   use of unconstructed message 'orgMessage'
>   '': message has not been initialized in

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the CopyMode property or File Adapter.  You should change the title.  Where does orgMessage come from?

Answer (score 5):

The error you got is not linked to the dynamic port neither the copy mode.
You are trying to assign to your message named "NewMessage" a message that is not constructed neither received in the orchestration.

Please check that the message named "orgMessage" is a message that was received via a receive shape or if it is constructed before your message assignment.

Comment: Also check that your construct shape is not trying to construct orgMessage again and only has NewMessage as the message to construct.

Comment: Hi thanks for your info.. check the construct message config and found that i have checked the orgMessage, when I unchecked it works fine..